# A simple button, when clicked increase a number by one

Tags: python, django

I am still a beginner, and tries to create a button, with no attachments to anything. The only thing that the button should do is to increase a number by one. Sort of like a like button, the model is just not attached to anything. I have tried a couple of things back and forth, and with the present code I can add a 'like' in the admin, but not on the button in the template.

I am missing the views for it, and that is where I need help (at least I think)

models

```
class Like(models.Model):
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

html

```
<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
            <div class='row'>
                {{ like.likes }}
                <input class='btn btn-success' type='submit' value='like'/>
                {{ like.count }}
                </div>
            </form>
```

and then what to put in the views?

Thanks in forehand

Comment: No need to use `form`, as pointed out in the answer below. Just make a `GET` request to the `view` and update the number of likes.

Comment: How would the syntax for that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ajax not a form

view

```
def update_like(request):
    like,created = Like.objects.get_or_create(pk=1, defaults={likes=1)})
    if not created:
        like.likes += 1
        like.save()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(like.likes), content_type='application/json')
```

html

```
<script>
function update_like()
{
   $.getJSON({% url 'update_like' %}, function( json ) {

   }

}
</script>


<a href="#" onclick="update_like();return false">Update like</a>
```

url

```
url(r'^/update-like/$', 'views.update_like', name='update_like'),
```

Comment: Great answer. How would the syntax look without the ajax? Is there a more simple/basic way to do it?

Comment: The problem with doing it without ajax is that you would need to redirect the page. This wouldn't make it generic.

Comment: I can't get it to work with the template. Isn't there missing some sort of render(request, 'like.html') in the views??